# ng-repeat - content to show if array is empty or null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a deep nested ng-repeat lists, and only in the last loop I've to display alternate content if list was empty. I'm new to angular, saw some posts online please help me where can I use content if list is empty. The `ng-repeat=sessions in day` could be empty.

```
<ul class="day">
        <li ng-repeat="sessions in day">
            <ul class="table-view">
                <li class="table-view-cell" ng-repeat="(heading, session) in sessions">
                    <span class="group">{{heading}}</span>
                    <ul class="cell">
                        <li class="cell-content" ng-repeat="val in session" ng-click="getSession(val.id)">
                            <div class="time" style="background-color:#{{val.color}}">
                                <span>{{val.start | date:"h:mma"}}</span>
                                <span>to</span>
                                <span>{{val.end | date:"h:mma"}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="session" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                                <span class="name">{{val.name}}</span>
                                <span class="room">Room: {{val.room}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**1). CSS approach.** I usually use pure CSS approach in such cases. With this markup (stripped extra-html):

```
<ul class="day">
    <li ng-repeat="sessions in day">
        ...
    </li>
    <li class="no-sessions">
        No sessions on this day.
    </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS rules to hide `.no-sessions` `li` by default and make it visible only if there are no previous `li` tags:

```
li.no-sessions {
    display: block;
}
li + li.no-sessions {
    display: none;
}
```

So when `sessions` array is empty, there will be no `li` rendered and only `no-sessions` one will be visible. And if will hide as soon as there is at least one session on this day.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/KqM9hfgTTiPlkdmEevDv?p=preview

**2). ngIf approach**. Of course you can use `ngIf/ngShow` directives for show no-records element when `sessions` array is empty:

```
<li ng-if="!day.length">
    No sessions on this day.
</li>
```

Comment: Cute! I like that. +1, Looks cleaner than using ng-hide / ng-show

Comment: It's not only cleaner, but also reduces number of watch functions making app a little faster.

Comment: So that's what the `+` css operator is for. Really nice trick, sir. _Have a beer!_

Answer (score 7):

I think this would work for your case:

```
    <li ng-hide="day.length > 0">
        No sessions on this day.
    </li>
```

No extra CSS needed. Assumes `day` is an array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WgDviOKjHKS1Vt5A5qrW

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend handling that in your controller. Keeping your logic in the controller and javasript makes debugging easier and more manageable. I can think of 2 approaches: using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` or a condition for your `day` variable when its empty.

**Option 1**

`ng-show/ng-hide` approach:

```
$scope.isDayEmpty = function(){
    return $scope.day.length > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

**html:**

```
<ul class="day">
    <li ng-repeat="sessions in day" ng-hide="isDayEmpty">
        ...
    </li>
    <li ng-show="isDayEmpty">
        No Sessions this Day
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Option 2:**

`ng-repeat` approach

```
if($scope.day.length == 0){
    $scope.day.push("No Sessions this Day");
}
```

This should get you essentially the same result. The first approach would make your CSS styling easier assuming you want to do something different in that case.

The second approach can vary in style depending on your code but thats an example of how you can do it. I don't know your javascript so I can't be more specific to your scenario.